# Rearranging data set in SAS

Tags: sas, transpose

I am new to SAS and am trying to rearrange a dataset. I feel that it shouldn't be too hard but I've been struggling with it for quite some time now. Here is what my dataset looks like

```
Factor Variable Value
A      X        1
A      Y        2
B      X        3
B      Y        4
```

and I want my resulting dataset to be

```
Variable   A   B
X          1   3
Y          2   4
```

Is this possible? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want values of variable `Value (VAR)` to be transposed to columns that will be named by values of `Factor (ID)` for each value of `Variable (BY)`, while not keeping the name of Value in an output field `_NAME_ (drop=_NAME_`).
I do admit I always need to play with it to get what I need.

```
data in;
length Factor Variable $1 Value 8;
input Factor Variable Value;
cards;
A      X        1
A      Y        2
B      X        3
B      Y        4
;
run;

proc sort data=in;
BY Variable;
run;

proc transpose data=in out=transp (drop=_NAME_);
ID Factor;
BY Variable;
VAR value;
run;

proc print noobs;run;
```

Comment: I always remember it by knowing that the `by` statement goes down the left, the `var` statement make up the metrics or the data that you want to keep and the `id` and `idlabel` statements make up the column names.  So the `by` and the `var` statements behave similar to `proc means` etc...